# facebook sdk for VS2008

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

is there any facebook sdk which can be used with VS2008??
i have downloaded some but they are not working with VS08 , i think they are compatible with VS10 only..
please provide me some useful link from where i can download something helpful to me..

Thanx in advance,
Sangeeta

Answer (score 0):

It requires VS2010 to build from source.

Here is the link on how to build Facebook C# SDK from source http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20Facebook%20C%23%20SDK

You can continue to use the compiled dll files in your applications. (the project needs to be .net 3.5 sp1 at minimum)